# Cassandra Cluster Architecture

Tags: architecture, cassandra, virtual-machine, titan

I am looking to create a cluster to use Cassandra and TitanDB for research.

Should I setup a cluster on three separate nodes (three desktops at home with 16gb ram & intel i7) or use a server (2 intel xeons and 32 gb ram) and create virtual nodes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It rather depends on what you are trying to do, or trying to find out.

For maximum performance and availability, you should use real nodes, not virtualised. But virtual nodes may be more convenient for experimentation, especially if you want to wipe and reconfigure them often. Another possibility is to use cloud VMs, which would enable you to scale out easily if required.

You don't state what kind of performance and storage you need. Consider whether you even need a cluster, or whether a single node would be enough for experimentation. Clearly this won't provide resilience in the face of disk failures etc. A single node on a single machine will probably out-perform virtualised nodes on the same hardware since there will be less contention for disk etc.

See also:

- [Cassandra Hardware](https://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/CassandraHardware) wiki page
- [Planning a cluster deployment](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/1.2/cassandra/architecture/architecturePlanningAbout_c.html)